# Deploying a Django site to GCP on App Engine, connecting App Engine to Cloud SQL

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I've followed two tutorials to deploy my Django app to App Engine and to connect to the database:

https://medium.com/@BennettGarner/deploying-a-django-application-to-google-app-engine-f9c91a30bd35
https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine

I have the app "succesfully" running atm, but from print statenments I can see from the log information that as soon as the site reaches a point where it needs to query the database it times out (after 5min or so).

So that suggests to me that there are some issues with the App Engine and Cloud SQL connection. I have succesfully the django site connected locally through the cloud sql proxy, and I try to deploy with the same configurations but doesn't seem to work.

I suspect that the issue is one of the following:

- The Cloud SQL Configs should be different when running the app locally vs. in app engine (settings.py)
- In some examples I've seen the Main.py contain a lot of stuff around the database connection, but in neither of the tutorials do they do this, for example this is the GCP tutorial on the main.py file: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard_python3/django/main.py

I've checked that all App Engines inside the project have access to CLoud SQL by default, and the user also has access (i've used it for access).

I'm not able to move forward currently, and looking for inspiration/clues/solutions on where to look next.

Error messages which show up in logs are:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that you changed the DEBUG variable on mysite/settings.py to FALSE before running gcloud app deploy? Also have you checked that the relevant service accounts involved have the correct [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/roles-and-permissions#serverless-roles-permissions)? Check into the App Engine logs and edit your post to include the specific error message when trying to connect to Cloud SQL from App Engine.

Comment: Hi, why would DEBUG variable need to be set to FALSE? I'm still debugging.  Check screenshot of log information following the last print statement which I have in the code.

Comment: I believed that launching the application to App Engine would mean that your application was running in production and therefore the change. I would recommend you to follow [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine) thoroughly in order to understand the differences of using the GAE_APPLICATION env variable to use the unix socket to connect to Cloud SQL when running in App Engine and localhost and the proxy while testing locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the host should be different when running locally vs. on GCP.

```
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/[YOUR-CONNECTION-NAME]',
            'USER': '[YOUR-USERNAME]',
            'PASSWORD': '[YOUR-PASSWORD]',
            'NAME': '[YOUR-DATABASE]',
        }
    }
else:
    # Running locally so connect to either a local MySQL instance or connect to
    # Cloud SQL via the proxy. To start the proxy via command line:
    #
    #     $ cloud_sql_proxy -instances=[INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME]=tcp:3306
    #
    # See https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql-connect-proxy
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'NAME': '[YOUR-DATABASE]',
            'USER': '[YOUR-USERNAME]',
            'PASSWORD': '[YOUR-PASSWORD]',
        }
    }
```